# Unable to connect to Sybase from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sybase

I am getting the below error when attempting to connect to a Sybase server from Eclipse. Below is the stack dump

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.sybase.ase.internal.connection.JDBCASEConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCASEConnectionFactory.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the Sybase JDBC driver (jconnect) to communicate with Sybase central via a Java application.

See [Installing jConnect for JDBC](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32179.0707/html/jconnig/BABIEGCG.htm) on the Sybase website.

If you are interested in migration from Sysbase to oracle, you can check my [blog](http://fundapass.blogspot.in/2012/05/migration-from-sybase-9-to-oracle-10-g.html)

Comment: I can't open the link, is it still up or is there an alternate link ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this means it cannot find the jconn3 class. Do you already have the JConnect or JTDS files on your filesystem?  I have both and both work with Sybase 15.x - more or less  :)

In my case I had an error like that and found I did not have the driver pointing to the correct path.  I  added the correct path to the jconn3.jar file to Driver Files tab on Edit Driver Definition and got connected.